# How to use Ternary operation for Linq insertion from form Correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, linq

I have a RadioButtonList that ss not required but if users don't make a selection an error is thrown. Could get some advice on figuring out the ternary operation that could help with checking if any is selected then add otherwise add null. This is what I have so far:

```
 rea.returning = rbReturning.SelectedItem.Text != " " ? rbReturning.SelectedItem.Text:null;
```

This actually still throws an error and I was not sure what other approach to take

Comment: Can you supply the error?

Comment: @nphx
Exception Message:

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: is `rea.returning` a `string` ? is it initialised ? return `String.Empty` instead of null and check using `String.IsNullOrEmpty()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no SelectedItem, then your initial check of SelectedItem.Text is what's throwing the exception.  Try something like:

```
return rbReturning.SelectedItem == null ? null : rbReturning.SelectedItem.Text;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting a `NullReferenceException` by attempting to access the `SelectedItem` property, try checking it for `null` instead.

```
rea.returning = rbReturning.SelectedItem == null ? null : rbReturning.SelectedItem.Text;
```

But usually the `Text` isn't meaningful data to the system, it is used for holding the friendly string representation of the `SelectedItem`'s data. Try using `Value` instead.

```
rea.returning = rbReturning.SelectedItem == null ? null : rbReturning.SelectedItem.Value;
```

That will get you the value that gets POSTed back in the form during post-back.